# Why does "delete node;" crash my C++ linked list application?

Tags: c++, linked-list

The jDeleteAfter method of my linked list class is supposed to delete the node immediately following the node passed as an argument.  If it is doing that, I do not know, but it is abruptly closing my console application when "delete tlp;" (Temp List Pointer) gets read.  My instructor, the users of a programming forum and I have yet to determine the root of this problem.

Written in Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2:

```
[source]
#include "JawaListT.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <new.h>

/*DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR*/
JawaListT::JawaListT()
{
    if((this->jHead = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT) && (this->jTail = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT))
    {
        this->jHead->jSetNext(this->jTail);
        this->jTail->jSetNext(this->jTail);
    }//end if allocated
}

/*INSERT NODE AFTER*/
void JawaListT::jInsertAfter(JawaLinkT* lp, int val)
{
    if(lp != NULL && lp != this->jTail)     //if passed not tail and not null
    {
        JawaLinkT* tlp;             //new list node

        if((tlp = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT) != NULL) //if dynamically allocated  
        {
            tlp->jSetNext(lp->jGetNext());  //temp.next = passed.next                   
            lp->jSetNext(tlp);      //passed.next = temp
            tlp->jSetValue(val);        //temp.data = val
        }//end if allocated
    }//end if not tail
}

/*INSERT NODE BEFORE*/
void JawaListT::jInsertBefore(JawaLinkT* lp, int val)
{
    if(lp != NULL && lp != this->jHead)     //if passed not head and not null
    {
        JawaLinkT* tlp;             //new list node

        if((tlp = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT) != NULL) //if dynamically allocated
        {
            tlp->jSetNext(lp->jGetNext());
            tlp->jSetValue(lp->jGetValue());
//          *tlp = *lp;         //copies passed node to temp node
            lp->jSetNext(tlp);      //passed.next = temp
            lp->jSetValue(val);     //passed.data = val
            if(lp == this->jTail)       //if passed is tail
            {
                this->jTail = tlp;  //tail is temp
                this->jTail->jSetNext(this->jTail); //tail.next = tail
            }//end if lp
        }//end if tlp
    }//end if head
}

/*REMOVE NODE AFTER*/
void JawaListT::jDeleteAfter(JawaLinkT* lp)
{
    if(lp != NULL && lp->jGetNext() != this->jTail) //if not tail and not null
    {
        JawaLinkT* tlp;             //temp pointer to node

        tlp = lp->jGetNext();           //temp = passed.next
        lp->jSetNext(tlp->jGetNext());      //passed.next = temp.next
        delete tlp;             //delete to what temp points
    }//end if next  

        /*code that did not work any better*/
//      tlp->jSetNext((lp->jGetNext())->jGetNext());    
//      delete lp->jGetNext();
//      lp->jSetNext(tlp);

/*Also tried declaring and/or deleting tlp outside of decision structure, and
jDeleteCurrent(tlp) since that function works properly.*/   
}

/*REMOVE CURRENT NODE*/
void JawaListT::jDeleteCurrent(JawaLinkT* lp)
{
    if(lp != NULL && lp != jHead && lp != jTail)    //if not head or tail, not null
    {   
        JawaLinkT* tlp;             //temp pointer to node

        tlp = lp->jGetNext();           //temp = passed.next
        *lp = *tlp;             //copy temp to passed
        if(tlp == jTail)            //if temp is tail
        {
            this->jSetTail(lp);     //tail = passed
            lp->jSetNext(lp);       //passed.next = passed
        delete tlp;             //delete to what temp points
        }//end if tail
    }//end if not head
}

/*LINEAR SENTINEL SEARCH*/
JawaLinkT* JawaListT::jFindItemS(int item)
{
    JawaLinkT* tlp;                 //temp pointer to node
this->jTail->jSetValue(item);               //tail.data = item

    for(tlp = jHead->jGetNext(); tlp->jGetValue() != item; tlp = tlp->jGetNext());
    /*INIT: node after head, EXIT: data found, UPDATE: increment node*/

    if(tlp == jTail)                //if sentinel found
            std::cout << item << " not in list" << std::endl;   

    return((tlp != this->jTail->jGetNext()) ? tlp : NULL);
    /*If sentinel not found, return proper node, else return null*/
}

[/source]
```

I use the class' sentinel search to traverse the list and provide the proper node as an argument for jDeleteAfter.

Comment: Please reformat your source code with at least four (4) spaces at the beginning of each line to make it more readable.

Comment: Erp, that didn't format the way I intended.  Thank you for the edit. (scuttles off to read about gdb)

Answer (score 2):

A simple hint: remove all the tests for allocation failure - they will never happen on a Windows platform amd complicate the code. And if they do happen, you don't recover from them, so the tests are doubly useless.

Comment: Neil: ignoring out of memory errors it bad practice. Don't teach this to newbees please.


For a "show a code-snippet to the internet" it's a good thing to get rid of them though.

Comment: In C++, the best practice is to ignore it - an exception will be thrown. Disabling the exception and then not dealing with the error, as the questioner does, is the worst possible practice.

Comment: As long as you're not on MSVC 6.0, which has a non-compliant operator new that returns NULL instead of throwing.  (It might even be busted in 2003, I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Some code review tips:

```
JawaLinkT* tlp;                         //new list node

if((tlp = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT) != NULL)
```

is more readable as:

```
if(JawaLinkT* tlp = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT)
```

(also, see Neil's comment above why using nothrow without actually doing anything about it)

The code is also littered with random potential memory leaks:

```
if((this->jHead = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT) && (this->jTail = new (nothrow) JawaLinkT))
// What if first new succeeds and second fails?
```

As to the question, this is a lot of code to read without so much as stack trace to look for just a generic bug, but I think jDeleteAfter may be implemented incorrectly. Consider the case when the function is passed the node BEFORE the tail. I'll cut it off there because it does look like homework; but if you are still having trouble, comment and I'll clarify.

EDIT: And I realized I was wrong. Nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a conflict with my delete statement in my virtual destructor.  It all works now.  Thanks for the look-over of my code.

As for the nothrows -- I do it that way because our text introduced the idea and I don't know how to handle exceptions yet.  Thanks for the advice, however.